# Алгоритм получение значений селекторов и их отправки методом POST - JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html5, post, checkbox

Здравствуйте JS скриптеры. При написании сайта у меня возникла проблемка: У меня есть несколько `<form><input type="checkbox" id="id" checked(или ничего)>` эти checkbox-ы имеют различия в значениях id и checked. Мне нужен алгоритм, который при нажатии на одну из этих checkbox брал id изменённого чекбокса и с другой переменной которая имеет значение 1 при изначально checked значении или 0 при изначально не имеющем значение checked checkbox-а имеющий данный id. После он должен методом POST отправить значения этих переменных в PHP файл допустим находящийся в директории "scripts/hidder.php". Ну или если это так сложно или не возможно... Хоть дайте алгоритм отправки тем же методом но значения id и value из `<form><input type="checkbox" id="id" checked(или ничего) value="число">`

Comment: Ну Вы и выражаетесь... Отправляются данные по полю `name`. Дайте чекбоксам разные имена и они все будут передаваться

Comment: Мне нужно работать только с конкретным, нажатым checkbox-ом и с его знaчениями id и checked(На худой конец значением value). Кстати можно и по name вместо id...

Comment: Так отправить нужно только значение выбранного чекбокса или всех? Вы так написали, что я даже перечитывать и разбираться не хочу - ахинея какая-то.

Comment: Так отправить нужно только значение выбранного чекбокса - Да.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {

  jQuery("#myform input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
    
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    vle = $(this).val();

    aj("scripts/hidder.php", false, "html", {
      "id": id,
      "value": vle
    }, s_hidder);
    
  });


  function s_hidder(result) {
    alert(result);   
  }


/*=======Функция универсального ajax запроса=======*/
  function aj(url, async, datatype, data, success) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      async: async, //СИНХРОННО ИЛИ АСИНХРОННО!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! (TRUE ИЛИ FALSE ПРИ ВЫЗОВЕ ФУНКЦИИ)
      //timeout: 20000, //Время ожидания выполнения запроса 20с.
      dataType: datatype,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }

}); //конец ожидания DOM
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" id='myform'>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="someting" id='id1' value="1">ch1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="someting" id='id2' value="2">ch2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="someting" id='id3' value="3">ch3</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Ого JQuery. Значит я получу переменные вида $_POST['id'] и $_POST['vle']?

Comment: "id": id, "value": vle. Имя переменных (которые вы получите) в двойных кавычках

Comment: вообще  лучше событие не click , change

Comment: Спасибо, именно так и сделал.